# Выделение сравнительного оборота

Tags: сравнительный-оборот

Как прошла репетиция? Вчера, как обычно, было, а сегодня — не знаю.

"Как обычно" выделяется запятыми?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятые были бы в контексте, где "как обычно" действует как вводное выражение (оно изымается без нарушения общего смысла):

> -- Сегодня будет яблоко к обеду? -- Вчера, как обычно, было, а сегодня — не знаю.

Но в примере с *репетицией* "как обычно" входит в составное именное сказуемое (как неразложимое наречное сочетание), оно тесно связано с глаголом "было" (при изъятии "как обычно" смысл разрушается) и отвечает на вопрос: "(было) как?" Это сочетание можно с сохранением смысла переставить (Вчера было как обычно...) и после этого даже заменить на "нормально". Обособление **не** нужно.